# XMLWorker not rendering full html on different machine

Tags: itext, xmlworker

I have some code which produces HTML and convert it to PDF correctly on my machine.

When I test the same code on different machine, some very simple text disappears from the generated PDF: what could be the reason? I have investigated the intermediate HTML and it is the same.

Does the locale affect rendering text from HTML to PDF? What others settings could be potentially affect that?

Comment: It's a strange problem. I assume you have checked the version numbers of iText/XML Worker on both configurations?

Comment: I build with Maven... 5.4.5  iText, 5.4.4 xmlWorker

Comment: Hmm, always keep the iText and XML Worker versions in sync (so use 5.4.5 or 5.4.4, don't mix them), but that doesn't explain the difference. What about the presence of fonts? Does the HTML require special fonts that are available on one system, but not on the other. Could it be an encoding problem?

Comment: Now that I think of it: do you think an exception is thrown silently. For instance: are there images in the PDF that can be reached from one system, but not from the other? Without more info, one can only guess... I'll post more comments when I think of more differences. For instance: are you using the same version of Java on both systems? (That shouldn't matter, but I want to exclude possible causes.)

Comment: It's a good idea, I will try to see if an exception is thrown silently. I am rather thinking about an encoding problem. I had tried with 1.6 and 1.7 on my machine it works in both cases

Comment: I don't think it's the locale, but could you check if the default locale on both machines is the same or not? Is it also possible for you to share your HTML and code? If not, could you share a similar HTML/code sample that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: One of the two machines had i-text 5.4 and the other 5.5, and now it's solved. However we have a strange issue now: on certain machines (linux)  the html is rendered to pdf with a larger font causing some carriage returns. might it depend on the font?